# PhoneGap iOS using an iframe won't load page

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an iframe that fetches information about a song and then it tries to launch iTunes. I have `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` with `YES` as the value, but when the frame tries to load the iTunes store. Here is the error:

```
shouldStartLoadWithRequest: Received Unhandled URL itms://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?term=It%27s+Happening+++Daniel+Bashta&partnerId=30&siteID=aOx3s4PxaYI-u3VQ6FY0xTj9XV2LxTTfDg
2012-07-27 13:46:05.115 Victory 91.5[7024:13403] Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted
```

If you have any suggestions, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with just a http request rather then itms?

Comment: Yes, that's how the request is, but when their page loads they automatically try to open iTunes.